# How to remove or minimise compression banding in Blender video export using FFmpeg?

Tags: video, compression

When exporting video with very subtle color blending like lights in fog a compressed video will create banding where there was none before, even with the best in-Blender settings e.g. "perceptually lossless" etc.

So far my best solution is to export all frames as .BMP image sequence. (exported PNG images have banding).

By using FFmpeg free software one can apply the following line:

```
ffmpeg -i "input%04d.bmp"  -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -tune film  -preset slow -crf 1 output.mp4
```

This will significantly reduce banding to almost unnoticeable or sometimes imperceptible.

I wonder if you have discovered a better method or better settings for FFmpeg? My solution above is an optimum between size and quality, but I am not an expert on FFmpeg.

Comment: Try WEBM/VP9 as the codec, I think it's basically h265 - so ought to be better then h264 for rendering gradients (you'd hope: it's somewhat newer!), it's probably still only 8bits deep though. I must admit I only really use FFMPEG or any animation type export from Blender for tests/previz though, if you want it really pretty go for anything 10bits or better deep, as in not 8bit PNGs or such like, and obviously low/no compression, then compile the animation in FFMPEG / Handbrake / Blackmagic Fusion or whatever.